# exact meaning of tag filtering regex

Tags: regex

next regular expression filters some html tags' style/src attribute.

```
[(?i:s\\*c\\*r\\*i\\*p\\*t)]
[(?i:e\\*x\\*p\\*r\\*e\\*s\\*s\\*i\\*o\\*n)]
```

Besides 'modifier span',
what is "\\*"?
Does it mean s*c*r*i*p*t ? Then, does it have any effect to filtering?

Comment: How is this quoted? What language? Can you show real code with this? `"\\*"` is usually `\*` which just escapes and matches a `*`, but the regex `\\*` escapes the \ and matches it 0 or more times.

Comment: finally I found the answer! http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html here comes the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In regex, `\\*` means 0 or more literal \ characters. So the regexes are looking for the words `script` and `expression`, possibly with any number of backslashes between the letters, and possibly with no backslashes at all.

Some examples that would match:

- `s\c\r\\ipt`
- `sc\\\\\ript`
- `s\\\c\r\\\ip\\\t`
- `script`

As **Qtax** points out, the language is going to be important here. I don't recognize that regex syntax, but some require backslashes to be double-escaped: once for the primary language, and once for the regex engine. That's a hard thing to explain, but basically it means that the patterns *might* only match the following two inputs, depending on the programming language:

- `s*c*r*i*p*t`
- `e*x*p*r*e*s*s*i*o*n`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a \ character in regex escapes special characters to suppress their special meaning.i.e \n would actually equate to \n instead of newline.

Simple as that!

Just to add to the answer, the characters in question would resolve to s\*c\*r\*i\*p\*t